# Can the ZedGraph charting library for .NET be recommended?

Tags: c#, graphics, charts, zedgraph

I am working on a project for my company, and I need to integrate some graphs of different types and average complexity to C# in the process of studying stock markets. I found this free library on the Internet, [ZedGraph](http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page). If you came across it, do you recommend using it? And how well is it supported?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I can recommend ZedGraph. I have been using it with great
success for several years in [MSQuant](http://msquant.sourceforge.net), for most plots: mass
spectrum display, recalibration error plots, LC peak plots,
quantitation profiles and others.

Here are some screen-shots from MSQuant where ZedGraph has
been used:

1. [Scatter plot, with trendline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvUae.png)
2. [X-Y plot with the actual data points shown, line connection data points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyznI.png)
3. [Sticks plot, with overlayed annotation (`TextBox`es, in fact)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CY5H.png)
4. [Several plots in the same window, types as in 2. and 3.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HG6Wb.png) (the two plots in the bottom half)
5. [Closer look at type 2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtFna.png)
6. [Collage, type 2. and code in Visual Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b94Zj.png)

The source code that is behind the first plot can be found in *[Source code for MSQuant: frmRecalibrationVisualisation.vb, MSQuant/msquant/src/GUI/forms/frmRecalibrationVisualisation.vb.](http://pmortensen.eu/1/MSQuant/MSQsrcWWW,1.5,2008-12-19/frmRecalibrationVisualisation.vb.html)*.

In contrast to many other charting libraries, ZedGraph can
also be used for scientific/math oriented plots/charts (for example,
scatter plots) and not only for business-type plots/charts.
Stock market applications may also need scatter plots.

In ZedGraph, there is built-in support for the user to zoom
in (infinite) and zoom out, pan (drag while holding down the
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key), save the plot to a file or copy it to the
clipboard.

There is one thing I am missing in ZedGraph: the ability for
the user to select items in the plot in order to perform
some action on those selected items (for example, computing some
number, accepting them as verified or marking them as
outliers to the application program).

Don't be put off by the state of ZedGraph's development.
ZedGraph is mature, is of very high quality, and can be used
as-is. There is supposed to be a new team behind its further
development.

Answer (score 6):

ZedGraph does not appear to be supported by the original developers anymore. However, you can find it as part of other projects where updates have been made.

For example, per [this discussion](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/forums/forum/392231/topic/3487337) on a ZedGraph project discussion list:

> So I highly optimized ZedGraph for all
> the curves, and objects. Basically, I
> optimized how it uses GDI and
> specifically made it only draw objects
> that will fit in the chart.
>
> So it scrolls and zooms now extremely
> efficiently even if I have many
> millions of objects on the chart. Plus
> it users nearly zero CPU when it's
> running in real-time as slower speeds
> for tracking financial charts.
>
> I fixed a few defects also.

You can find a fork of the repo with the changes [here](https://github.com/jspraul/TickZoomPublic/tree/integrate/Platform/ZedGraph).

Comment: Link is broken, do you know if we can still find this optimized version?

Answer (score 5):

I strongly recommend the [Microsoft Chart Controls For .NET Framework 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en) over ZedGraph.

Comment: MS Chart may only be used in conjunction with a valid Windows license. For some products, clients or people this is a complete no-go.

Comment: nevertheless this is a good find and deserves +1 imo. Thanks Jamie Ide.

Comment: Why do you recommend this?

Comment: @StealthRabbi In 2015, I recommend HighCharts (there's a .NET wrapper) or D3.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean Zedgraph rather than Zgraph? Zedgraph's homepage is [**here**](http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page) and is described in a CodeProject article [**here**](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/zedgraph.aspx).
If you are talking about Zedgraph I can recommend it, I have relatively little experience in C# but quite a lot in data visualization. I found it straightforward to get Zedgraph up and running and producing good-looking charts. Zedgraph is very good for 2D charting, I'm still looking for an equivalent for 3D plotting.

Answer (score 2):

I hate to be a killjoy, but I wouldn't recommend ZedGraph.

I was working with it a couple of years ago and noticed that the support was provided by a single enthusiast that seemed abused by everyone wanting his freeware with no compensation or contributions.  It's a curse faced by a lot of [FOSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_software) authors.

It doesn't look like the software has been updated in over a year now and the help forum is full of queries with no responses.  It looks like the author lost interest and walked.

If you use ZedGraph, do it because you want to maintain the underlying code and because you want to contribute back to the user/developer community.  If you have no interest in contributing, and you can't maintain it for yourself, be prepared for things that don't work and simply never will.  An enterprising company could sponsor the development of the software and offer for-fee support, but you need to decide for yourself if it's good enough to do that and if there is a real revenue model.

Comment: Why do something have to be under constant development to be useful? ZedGraph just works.

Comment: Ya got the source code, it is as good as your own. C#/.NET developers are some of the most common these days, anyway.

Comment: I know this answer is late and the author is gone. It is important to mention that [ZedGraph author died in 2009](https://obits.ocregister.com/obituaries/orangecounty/obituary.aspx?n=john-champion&pid=123637224) and what is written regarding interrest losing and walking away is not true. ZedGraph is mature and alive, and its source code has been forked more than one hundred of time. Obviously the author knew what "simplicity" means : not only ZedGraph is perfectly usable out of the box, but it is elegant vision makes it very easy to extend and to customize.

Answer (score 0):

Although development seems to have stalled, [WPF Dynamic Data Display](http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com/) looked promising.

Answer (score 0):

ZedGraph does not support 3D graphing, such as Surface Chart: Implied Vol Surface